# Why when i press a textbox with text do action?

Tags: javascript, php

When I click on the textbox with the text I do the action I want when I click the button to do the action

My PHP Code

```php
    <form  onClick="getSpecialData(this)" action="" method="GET">

    <input <?php echo $disabled; ?> name="textarea" maxlength="20" id="needid" required placeholder="<?php echo $lang['SEASONS_WRITE_HERE'] ; ?>">
    <input <?php echo $disabled; ?> name="special" id="needid" hidden value="<?php echo $row['action'];?>">
    <button <?php echo $disabled; ?> type="button" class="buy_input_button" name="submit_special"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></button>
  </form>
```

and javascript code

```js
 function getSpecialData(fmm) {
   $.ajax({
     url: 'config/getData.php',
     type: 'post',
     data: 'submit_special='+$(fmm).find('button[name="submit_special"]').val()+'&special='+$(fmm).find('input[hidden]').val()+'&textarea='+$(fmm).find('input[required]').val(),
     success: function(data) {
       $('body').append(data);
 }
   });
 }
```

Comment: Please clarify the desired behavior, the problem, and your specific question. Please don't just post "why doesn't this work?" type questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the onclick out of your form element and put it in your button element, that is inside the form.

```
<button onclick="getSpecialData(this.form)">clickme</button>
```